# Moving custom options box on Magento products

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento, e-commerce

I need to move the my product options to the product info column on every product in my Magento store.  To do this manually I navigate to manage products, pick a product > design > "Display Product Options in".  The problem is that I have thousands of products.

I have been searching through databases in Cpanel trying to find where this option exists so that I can write a query to change it for my entire store.  Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can change this option for every product at once?

Thank you I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the import functional will suit your needs best. Create a CSV file with **sku** and **options_container** columns and insert into the latter column value *container1*. Use **Import All Products** DataFlow profile. Should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from Admin panel.Go to

- Catalog->Manage Products
- Select the list of the products.click Update Attributes from Action
  Menu
- Change the value for "Display Product Options In" and save

Comment: I've had an issue doing it this way because attributes like "brand" are required fields, and not all of my products are of the same brand.  Is there a way to update only the desired attribute?